# CMD closes immediately after opening it

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

## My problem

I am trying to open a command prompt like this:

#### Step 1

press windows+run

#### Step 2

Write `cmd`

#### Step 3

Press enter

#### Result

Cmd briefly opens then closes

## Causes

Recently i had a malware but i cleaned it with MalwareBytes, still this could be a follow-up of that

## Other weird behaviour

- When i go to `windows/system32` and I right click `cmd.exe` to see it's properties it doesn't allow me to do it, acts just like if I would have clicked away, on the other hand i can see the properties for other files
- If i right click the start icon and run command prompt from there it allows me to use cmd perfectly
- I can't open `.cmd` files

## What I've tried

1. I ran `sfc` for cmd and it closed my command prompt
2. I checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` for any autoruns but i found none
3. I checked with the program `autoruns` if there are any autoruns on the cmd and i couldn't found any

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a virus. Try booting into safe mode and see if things run normally.

Comment: I think you can refer to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373137/cmd-exe-closes-immediately-after-calling-win7-64

Comment: everytime I try to acess the link you posted my browser closes? I'll do another scan to see if I find something

Comment: Also when I start it in safe mode cmd opens with no problem

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a virus. Safe mode might fix that: Restart into safe mode and try opening CMD. Then it should run normally.